# Как настроить проект (react+Node.JS+WebPack) в WebStorm для дебага

Tags: node.js, webstorm, webpack-dev-server, nodemon

Имеется проект Node.JS + Webpack.
Запускаю nodemon и webpack-devserver - работает, но без дебага.
Как настроить проект в WebStorm, чтобы можно было дебажить?

```
global.Promise         = require('bluebird');
const webpack            = require('webpack');
const path               = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin  = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const publicPath         = 'http://localhost:8050/public/assets';
const cssName            = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'styles-[hash].css' : 'styles.css';
const jsName             = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'bundle-[hash].js' : 'bundle.js';

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
'process.env': {
  BROWSER:  JSON.stringify(true),
  NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
}
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin(cssName)
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  plugins.push(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([ 'public/assets/' ], {
      root: __dirname,
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    })
  );
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
  debug: true,
  resolve: {
    root:               path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules' ],
    extensions:         ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/public/assets/`,
    filename: jsName,
    publicPath
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader')
      },
      { test: /\.gif$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg' },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' },
      { test: /\.svg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1' },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'react-hot!babel!eslint-loader' : 'babel',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/] },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  eslint: { configFile: '.eslintrc' },
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  }
};
```

Comment: в целом для отладки react приложений необходимо создать javascript Debug ран конфигурацию. Если создание сорсмапов в webpack конфигурации настроено правильно, больше в общем ничего не нужно. См. https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/

Comment: так и сделал, запускаю дебаг, он запускается, но ни одного брекпоинта не ловит. Вкинул несколько строк для логирования в JSX-модули -- ни единый лог не сработал

Comment: Мистика - пишу строку `console.log('breckpoint');` и ставлю на нее брек - в консоль сервера запись сделало, но выполнение не останавливало

Comment: скорее всего, проблема в настройках проекта. Ничего определенного без проекта сказать нельзя

Comment: package.json

    {
      "name": "B-app",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "set NODE_ENV='development' && webpack -p",
        "webpack-devserver": "webpack-dev-server --debug --hot --devtool eval-source-map --output-pathinfo --watch --colors --inline --content-base public --port 8050 --host 0.0.0.0",
        "nodemon": "set NODE_PATH=./src; && nodemon server.js"
      },
      "author": "B-cor",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {

Comment: для начала я бы поменяла `--devtool eval-source-map` на `--devtool source-map`. Это не обязательно поможет. но вдруг:)